# Why the order of array when insert it into database using map, forEach and for loop is different

Tags: javascript

I have an array [1,2,3,4,5] and when insert into database I except to receive result be like [1,2,3,4,5] in database. But only loop for give me an expected result, map() and forEach() always give me disorder array like [1,3,4,5,2] or [4,3,2,5,1] and so on.
This is my code:

```
arrayChild.map(async item => {
    await this.repository.save(item)
});

arrayChild.forEach(async item => {
    await this.repository.save(item)
});

for (let i = 0; i < arrayChild.length; i++) {
    await this.repository.save(arrayChild[i])
}
```

Please give me the reason. Thank for your attention

Comment: Because you're not actually waiting for each item to be inserted with `map` or `forEach`.

Comment: Your loops all initiate **asynchronous** operations, and you cannot rely on them finishing in any particular order. Even with the `for` loop, you probably just got lucky. If you want the ordering at your server to be predictable, send the value *and* the index. *edit* — the `for` loop may be different, I haven't had enough coffee to think about it.

Comment: Pointy is right, and luckily I've had some coffee today. `for` loops actually works differently and will perform the operations in order if you use it in combination with `await`. This is a good blog article showing asynchronous operations used in different types of loops (https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/)

Comment: Even though it works in the way you want it to in `for` loops, I wouldn't recommend you to use it as it has some performance downsides. The solution proposed by @Pointy is better (you can read more here why that's so: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `map` and `forEach` methods don't handle the asynchronous function you passed in an `async await` way.

When you check the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#polyfill) of both method, you'll find a line like this `callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);`. So, basically, it just execute the `callback`. If the `callback` is an asynchronous method, it doesn't wait its execution to be done. Instead, it continue executing other codes.

So, when you save your array of data to database, your callbacks inside `map` & `forEach` just issue a few query, the final order of database's execution may be uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

Because `await` doesn't work in forEach and map methods, it is not asynchronous. Therefore, when you use await in forEach or map methods to save data into db, it will run the loops silmutaneously and the results will be in disordered way.