# Missing updated record when using map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

This is my code for update many records with mongodb.

```
const nfts = await waxModel.find();
console.log(nfts.length) // -> 121

// Option 1: using map()
nfts.map(async nft => {
    nft.trait_attribute = null;
    await nft.save();
  });

// Option 2: using loop
for (let i = 0; i < nfts.length; i++) {
    nfts[i].trait_attribute = null;
    await nfts[i].save();
  }
```

- This is my DB, no recored have trait_attribute: null:

[image]

- This is the first result when I use map(), only have 2 records:

[image]

- And this is the second result when I use for loop:

[image]

I don't know that is the problem. In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69798224/why-the-order-of-array-when-insert-it-into-database-using-map-foreach-and-for-l): I know map methods don't handle the asynchronous function but it's still have full records not missing many updated records as now.
Thank for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code doesn't handle race conditions well.

The first option saves every nft simultaneously whilst the second one saves them one at a time. A more readable way to do that would be using a for-of loop:

```js
for (const nft of nfts) {
  nft.trait_attribute = null;
  await nft.save();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but with for I can save the entire records.

Comment: And so does this for loop. The next step would be to find a way to save them faster, asynchronously.